# NamedCredential Update using Apex after Sandbox Refresh to avoid PROD reference

Tags: apex, namedcredentials

My Requirement is to update Endpoint and give (X) in password after sandbox refresh to avoid PROD reference. I am Okay if only Endpoints can be updated. Tried below Snippets and running this from console/workbench but getting error.
Anyone please suggest where and how should I run the update script.

**Option 1:**

```
List<NamedCredential>  lstval= [SELECT DeveloperName,Endpoint,Id,MasterLabel,NamespacePrefix FROM NamedCredential order by DeveloperName];
List<NamedCredential> updatelstVal= new List<NamedCredential>();

if(lstval !=null && lstval.size()>0){
  for(NamedCredential val:lstval){
      if(val.Endpoint!=null){
       val.Endpoint=val.Endpoint+'__TEST'; // Changing the EndPoint to avoid PROD calls.
       val.principalType = 'NamedUser';
       val.protocol = 'NoAuthentication';
       updatelstVal.add(val);
     }
  }
 }

 System.debug('%%%'+updateMetadata(credential));
```

Error Message: COMPILE ERROR: Field is not writeable: NamedCredential.Endpoint LINE: 7 COLUMN: 12

---

**Option 2:**

```
List<MetadataService.NamedCredential>  lstval= [SELECT DeveloperName,Endpoint,Id,MasterLabel,NamespacePrefix FROM MetadataService.NamedCredential order by DeveloperName];
    List<MetadataService.NamedCredential> updatelstVal= new List<MetadataService.NamedCredential>();

    if(lstval !=null && lstval.size()>0){
      for(MetadataService.NamedCredential val:lstval){
          if(val.Endpoint!=null){
           val.Endpoint=val.Endpoint+'__TEST'; // Changing the EndPoint to avoid PROD calls.
           val.principalType = 'NamedUser';
           val.protocol = 'NoAuthentication';
           updatelstVal.add(val);
         }
      }
     }
 System.debug('%%%'+updateMetadata(credential));
```

*Error Message: COMPILE ERROR: Invalid type: MetadataService.NamedCredential LINE: 1 COLUMN: 1*

Comment: The [latest version of the MetaDataApi Wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)  supports NamedCredentials. That said, I'm not sure how one would use it in a sandbox refresh as there is no first class session to authenticate with

Answer (score 0):

I think `NamedCredential` can only be read through SOQL and fields are readonly.

So, you can explore protected custom settings to store the end points which you can update from apex.